# How can I freely move this function to the left?

Tags: polynomials, graphing-functions

y=-6x²²+3x²+4 [equation at desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/utedi9bnjw?lang=en)

Comment: Try the input $y = -6(x-a)^{22} + 3(x-a)^2 + 4$ and add a slider for $a$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace y= with f(x)=

And now graph f(x+c) for any value c.

This can be used for any function and will move it laterally.